# compositor rerender layer

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

This is my preview render in the *3D Viewport*.

[image: preview of layer 01 = render layer 01]

When I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, I get this  render result:

[image: render result of layer 01]

I achieved the render result in the compositor before I changed some things in *Layer 1*.

This is the compositor node setup. Of course I reconnected to the composite node,
twice at least

[image: compositor node setup]

Does anyone know what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

As for the question if I changed anything in 3DView or render layer. Both. First
in 3DView, of course, than I deleted all render layers - still same render result.

[image]

Comment: You can now upload that third picture. It would also help if you _Packed External Data_ and uploaded your .blend to [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Comment: Did you change things in 3D view layer, or in render layer?

Comment: @anon please [edit] your question and add more information about your file, it's very hard to guess what you've done or how you set up your render layers or the compositor nodes. Please consider uploading your file and making the link available as part of the question. Please use : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also the compositor screen shot is too small to read.

Comment: it's not really to read - I tried so many things after the problem above, and before taking a screen shot. The point is: the render layer node has one render layer in its drop down menu selected and still doesn't show the thumbnail